# How quickly is the deauthorize callback pinged?

Tags: facebook, authentication, authorize

As the question says basically.

After going to Privacy Settings and removing the app, how long does it take for Facebook to ping the deauthorize URL specified?

I'm trying to find out if my page isn't working or if I'm just supposed to be waiting longer.

Answer (score 0):

It's being called almost instantly now.
It must have just been a bug before.